# create jar with dependencies in maven project

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml, executable

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAssure</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.test.decimal.rest.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Executed the jar from command prompt:

`java -jar TestAssure-1.0.1.jar`

Getting Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
                at com.test.decimal.rest.Main.main(Main.java:9)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You should execute the fat jar, which includes project's dependencies.

It should be located under `target` directory, containing `jar-with-dependencies` in its filename.